# UPDATE statement not working, but works in phpMyAdmin & live host

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this update statement below:

```
string_from_base64_encode_ends_with = base64_encode(serialize($_POST));

UPDATE members SET settings = 'string_from_base64_encode_ends_with=='
WHERE email = "right@emailhere.com" AND active=1
```

1. (localhost) When I process with `mysql_query()`, the real record is not updated, although **`mysql_affected_rows()`** **returns 1**
2. (localhost) But when I copy this **UPDATE statement then process through phpMyAdmin**; it works, mysql_affected_rows() returns 1 & **real record really updated**
3. (live host) With these codes, no change, **when I run on a live host; all are very good: record updated**,  mysql_affected_rows() returns 1

May you help me find out there something wrong with MySQL server? Or some thing else?

Many thanks

PS: all other UPDATE statements are still fine on both localhost & live host, updated; this statement is problem only

Comment: can you give more php code .

Comment: really thank you, but the code is just that; here's more explainations

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the string using mysql_real_escape_string()

```
$string = mysql_real_escape_string("string_from_base64_encode_ends_with==");
 mysql_query("UPDATE members SET settings = '".string ."' WHERE email = \"right@emailhere.com\" AND active=1");
```

Comment: how is that going to make any difference?